# different hover colors required for different sections of a single image

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'm having difficulty with applying hover styles for an image. The image is having an irregular shape plus each section when hovered needs to have a different hover color.

[image]

Comment: add your HTML & CSS like jsfiddle

Comment: please show some code

Comment: What do you mean hover color? Do you want to add a semi-transparent color on top of the image, do you want to completely override the image, do you just want to color in that section?

Comment: I just want to color only a specific section where the mouse is hovered not the entire image

Comment: That's complicated unless all you want is for all the "hover colors" to be displayed whenever the cursor is somewhere over the image, in which case you could just switch to a second image (such as by toggling the `style` attribute's `display` property on each image.)  If you want the DOM to handle each portion of the image as a separate entity, you likely have to tell it exactly which pixels count as which portion (possibly by breaking the image into several separate elements that look to humans as if they're one thing.) I expect the `canvas API` or the `SVG element` will be instrumental.

Comment: Your image looks very much like it might be a vector image, if so using this as a SVG would make this very easy.

Answer (score 1):

SVG's are really good for this, and looking at your image it looks like it's already a vector image anyway.  If so save the image as an SVG, svg's are plain text, you can then give parts classnames, id's etc, and you can style your hover effects using simple CSS.

Below is an example, mouse over the black circles to see it change to different colours.

```css
circle:nth-child(1):hover { fill: red; }
circle:nth-child(2):hover { fill: green; }
circle:nth-child(3):hover { fill: blue; }
circle:nth-child(4):hover { fill: yellow; }
circle:nth-child(5):hover { fill: green; }
circle:nth-child(6):hover { fill: purple; }
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30"/>
  <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="30"/>
  <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="30"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="120" r="30"/>
  <circle cx="150" cy="120" r="30"/>
  <circle cx="250" cy="120" r="30"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Area Map. The syntax is as follows:

```
<map name="myMap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,20" href="somelink.html">
  <area shape="circle" coords="10,30,50,100" href="anotherlink.html">
</map>
```

You use the coords to define each area. You then can assign an ID to each area and make the hover items. Try it and let us know.

You can use an Image Map Generator online, there are plenty. I use this one: http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/ It is much easier than doing it on your own.

Comment: You can not style `area` elements so how would this help?